# Adding different vertical lines on facets ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I am quite a newbie to RStudio and I am having problems adding *different* vertical lines on each of my two facets using facet_wrap

Here is what I thought:

```
library(ggplot2)

g <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=index, na.rm= TRUE))

d <- g+ geom_density() + facet_wrap(~gender)

vline.data <- data.frame(z = c(2.36,2.48),gender = c("Female","Male")) 

d1 <- d + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = z),vline.data)
```

But it adds the same two lines to each facet -  what would you reckon is the problem? I have thought of somehow splitting the facets into two separate data frames, but I have no idea how to go on about it.

P.S The x-axis (the index) goes from 1 to 4.

Thank you in advance.

```
        index  <-  c(NA, NA, 4, 4, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
        3, NA, 3, NA, NA, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, NA, 4, 2, 
        4, 4, 2, 2, NA, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, NA, NA, 2)

       gender <-  c("Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", 
        "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", 
        "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", 
        "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", 
        "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", 
        "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", 
        "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male")
```

Using the code and data above I get [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vE9y1.png)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please read about [how to make a great reproducible question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi, this doesn't seem to be the problem. Maybe I didn't ask my question very well - I want to add the one line only to one facet and the other one to the other. 2.36 only to the facet corresponding to female and 2.48 to the male facet

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Add Lines With A Facet R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58141541/how-to-add-lines-with-a-facet-r)

Answer (score 1):

This was asked a long time ago, but here's the answer:

You need to add `geom_vline` to your ggplot. `geom_vline` takes a single value, not a vector, and it doesn't iterate, so you can't have multiple values in a separate data object from the rest of your data. Merge `vline.data` as a new column with the rest of `dat` as is appropriate for your data set. This question doesn't have reproducible data, but put `index`,`gender` and however you calculate `vline.data` into a single `dat` dataframe with each of those pieces as column names. Then you can `summarise` the `vline.data`. The example below assumes the values within `vline.data` are the mean values for the entire `index` column.

```
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=index, na.rm= TRUE)) +
  geom_density() + 
  facet_wrap(. ~ gender) +
  geom_vline(data = . %>% group_by(gender) %>% summarise(vl=mean(index)), 
             aes(xintercept=vl))
```

[How to Add Lines With A Facet R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58141541/how-to-add-lines-with-a-facet-r)