# How to Add Lines With A Facet R

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

So I have a faceted graph, and I want to be able to add lines to it that change by each facet.

Here's the code:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt))+
  geom_histogram(bins = 20,aes(fill = factor(cyl)))+
  facet_grid(.~cyl)+
  scale_color_manual(values = c('red','green','blue'))+
  geom_vline(xintercept = mean(mtcars$wt))

p
```

So my question is, how would I get it so that the graph is showing the mean of each faceted sub-graph.

I hope that makes sense and appreciate your time regardless of your answering capability.

Comment: Would you consider calculating means separately (summarize) and then setting `xintercept` to that? Seems like that might be reasonable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this within the ggplot call by using `stat_summaryh` from the `ggstance` package. In the code below, I've also changed `scale_colour_manual` to `scale_fill_manual` on the assumption that you were trying to set the fill colors of the histogram bars:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggstance)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt))+
  geom_histogram(bins = 20,aes(fill = factor(cyl)))+
  stat_summaryh(fun.x=mean, geom="vline", aes(xintercept=..x.., y=0), 
                colour="grey40") +
  facet_grid(.~cyl)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('red','green','blue')) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Another option is to calculate the desired means within `geom_vline` (this is an implementation of the summary approach that @Ben suggested). In the code below, the `.` is a "pronoun" that refers to the data frame (`mtcars` in this case) that was fed into ggplot:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt))+
  geom_histogram(bins = 20,aes(fill = factor(cyl)))+
  geom_vline(data = . %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(wt=mean(wt)), 
             aes(xintercept=wt), colour="grey40") +
  facet_grid(.~cyl)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('red','green','blue')) +
  theme_bw()
```